# Create Table fails in sqlyog

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   product VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   quantity INT,
   price DECIMAL(18,2)
);
```

error is

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   product VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   quantity INT,
   pr' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   product VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   quantity INT,
   price DECIMAL(18,2)
);
```

This worked. I removed `IDENTITY`. [I do not see `IDENTITY` in the create table doc of MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

---

**EDIT1** (got that OP's wrong syntax exported from T-SQL)

Ahh I got it... you are taking the SQL from T-SQL? Perhaprs you need auto increment use this

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   product VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   quantity INT,
   price DECIMAL(18,2)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   product VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   quantity INT,
   price DECIMAL(18,2)
);
```